# How to force redirect to https when user changes the url to be http://whatever?

Tags: java, scala, http, https, playframework

I'm using play framework 2.3 and I've got to the point where redirecting to https is working but if I change the https in the url to http, the request never makes it to the server. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

if your app working behind a web server, simple create same backend config for http and https. you can find different web server configs in official documentation:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/HTTPServer

if your app handling https directly (not recommended) and you start it with `./start -Dhttps.port=...` add another argument `-Dhttp.port=` then your server accessible with https and http request.

the best scenario if you use a web server in front of your app, and configure http to https redirecting there.

eg. nginx http host config to redirect every request to https:

```
server {
 include /etc/nginx/server_http;
 server_name  yourdomain.com;

 root /var/www/html;

 location / {
  rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri?;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use two server config first one with port 80 any one open it will redirect to only https

```
    server {
listen       80;
        server_name  domain   www.doman ;
return         301 https://www.doman.com$request_uri;
}
################################################
server {
    location ~ /\. { deny  all; }
listen              443 ssl;
server_name        domain   www.doman  ;
```